# Why I don't have the good behavior when I select a grid with Vaadin?

Tags: grid, vaadin, apache-cayenne

I'm working on Vaadin, 
I'm trying to print data in a grid. I want to select this data. Previously I wanted to edit the data but it seems to be before the edit.[I took a look to : https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html#figure.components.grid.editing]

But when I have more then one row, it will always edit or select my first row.

See: Before any edit/select, it print the good values :
[image]

But when I try to edit/select the second row (just click on it), I have : 
[image]
That should be the user id :2, the first name :wc, the last name : sdsdf, ...

My code is :

```
   grid.setItems(getUsersInfo());

   grid.addColumn(UserInfo::getUserId).setCaption("User Id");
   grid.addColumn(UserInfo::getFirstname).setCaption("First Name")
        .setEditorComponent(firstNameEditor, UserInfo::setFirstName);
   grid.addColumn(UserInfo::getLastname).setCaption("Last Name")
        .setEditorComponent(lastNameEditor, UserInfo::setLastName);
   grid.addColumn(UserInfo::getEmail).setCaption("Email")
        .setEditorComponent(emailEditor, UserInfo::setEmail);
   grid.addColumn(UserInfo::getAddress).setCaption("Address")
        .setEditorComponent(addressEditor, UserInfo::setAddress);
   grid.addColumn(UserInfo::getPhonenumber).setCaption("Phone Number");

   grid.setSizeFull();
   grid.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
   grid.getEditor().setEnabled(true);

   setCompositionRoot(grid);
```

Any help will be very helpful !Thanks

EDIT : My class UserInfo is a user object (getter and setter) typically :

```
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        super.setFirstname(firstName);
    }
```

My class _UserInfo is extends from CayenneDataObject :

```
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        writeProperty(FIRSTNAME_PROPERTY, firstname);
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return (String)readProperty(FIRSTNAME_PROPERTY);
    }
```

EDIT 2 : 
When I just print the data without edit, I have the same issue when I select one data, my code is :

```
final VerticalLayout vlayout = new VerticalLayout();

userInfo = getUsersInfo();
grid.setItems(userInfo);

grid.addColumn(UserInfo::getUserId).setCaption("User Id");

grid.setSizeFull();


vlayout.addComponent(new HeaderMenu());
vlayout.addComponent(grid);

vlayout.setSizeFull();
setCompositionRoot(vlayout);
```

EDIT 3: After debugging step by step, I found where is the issue :
the issue is where I get my userId :

The error is:

```
Exception processing async thread queue
Exception processing async thread queue
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIType cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jdt.debug.core.IJavaReferenceType
```

On :

```
public int getUserId() {
    return (getObjectId() != null && !getObjectId().isTemporary()) ? (short) getObjectId()
            .getIdSnapshot().get(USERID_PK_COLUMN) : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a bad misake ! I did not need to define getter and sette in the object UserInfo, I should take data from _userInfo